# Ajax dropdown does not work on all browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have two dropdowns where one is being populated as per the other's selection (via ajax). I have been struggling to find out why it does not work on all browsers, for example, in latest Chrome it works fine, IE Version 11 as well.. However, on IE -8-9 it doesn't.. I have tried on multiple android devices with androids default browser...Without success

I have reproduced the same example live hoping someone can tell me if the problem is from the script.Does it have to do with Jquery?

Note: if you notice the ajax before send command is working as it shows loading then the returned data does not show in the dropdown...

I am using the same Bootstrap and Jquery versions( as included in the file )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `demo.php` script seems to return the complete `select` element :

```
<select name='size' ><option value='SMALL'>SMALL</option><option value='X-SMALL'>X-SMALL</option></select>
```

Try to return only the options part

```
<option value='SMALL'>SMALL</option><option value='X-SMALL'>X-SMALL</option>
```

Comment: I feel so dumb Philippe.. Thanks alot! Why do you think Chrome does not catch such errors?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think, modern browsers adapt their behaviour when they catch invalid dom.